# Windows Machines dropping connection to local linux site

Tags: linux, windows, networking, connection

**Problem**
We host a website locally for employees to use to complete their work.  We noticed once and a while an employee will lose connection to the local website and can not access the site anymore even though other employees still can.  We found that the machines that are having the problem have static IP's and according to one employee it happens when they come back from a break.

**Troubleshooting**
The employee only loses access to that site but still can access the internet and OTHER local websites we host on different servers.  Ping & Traceroute work fine from the PC to the server they can not access.

**Current Solution**
Unplugging the network cable and plugging it back in fixes the problem.

**Additional Info**
**Employees PC** - Windows XP & Windows 7 ( Ones losing connection to server )
**Server** - Linux ( Centos )

**UPDATE**
Server information
Centos 5.8
Apache 2.2.3
PHP 5.3.19
mySQL 5.5.28

Employees are accessing the server through chrome using the domain name not IP ( HTTPS )

Comment: Is there any chance of an IP conflict? Another computer getting a DHCP address that clashes with one of the statically assigned ones? Does clearing the arp cache with 'arp -d *' make any difference when it's not working? Do you access the website by hostname or IP - and does DNS still work when the site is unavailable? What error message do you get when it's not working? Tried newer NIC drivers? Do they run McAfee / other web filtering AV software?

Comment: Since you mention in passing that they don't have problems accessing other websites then I presume they are accessing the Linux machine using HTTP? (this would have been helpful to know). What browser? (Chrome can be a bit aggressive with keepalives).

Comment: It could perhaps be a server misconfiguration, though that doesn't seem very likely in your case. Still, you should add information about your HTTP server and version and perhaps anything special you're running with it.

Comment: I will have to wait for the error to crop up again to try some of these suggestions.

Comment: If it was IP conflict wouldn't it cause more problems? Also doesn't windows give you errors saying there is a conflict.

Comment: @symcbean It happened again and we tried using a new browser ( IE ) to open the page and it worked! The Chrome page wouldn't work even after closing Chrome and opening again.  Any ideas on why this is happening to the browser and how to fix?

Comment: It sounds like a network fault - could be all sorts of things - badly configured firewall, DHCP recycling too fast, poorly written AV software modifying the winsock behaviour... you'd need to identify the fault first.